# ReferenceError: en_EN is not defined right way to concatenate strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate some strings in Javascript with this code:

```
var locale = {{ app.request.locale }}_{{ app.request.locale | upper }} + '.json';
```

Where `{{ app.request.locale }}` gets `en` or `es` or `fr` or something else. The idea is to get this `en_EN.json` as result in locale but seems to be I'm doing wrong since I get this error on Firebug console:

```
ReferenceError: en_EN is not defined
    var locale = en_EN + '.json';
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, to avoid Javascript seeing the variable as var and not as string only need to change this:

```
var locale = "{{ app.request.locale }}_{{ app.request.locale | upper }}" + ".json";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of library you are using for replacing

```
{{ app.request.locale }}_{{ app.request.locale | upper }}
```

It is considering `en_EN` as a `variable` not `String`

**Sample Code Run - Concatenation of an undefined variable with a String**

[image]

Comment: This is not a library, this code is because the JS is on a Twig template and `{{ app.request.locale }}` give me `en` as result, now which is the best way to fix the issue related to non string value?

Comment: @ReynierPM I would advise that in future questions, you mention that this is part of a Twig template and not make people guess. The people reading your question would have no way of knowing that.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks for the suggestion, I'll as you said